# Chrome only sets the first cookie from the 'Set-Cookie' header

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, cookies, http-headers

I have a dead simple http nodejs server:

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'age=44; name=ok; something=else; path=/');
    res.end('ok ok ok', 'utf8');
}).listen(9999);
```

Upon visiting the page in the latest version of Chrome, these are the Response Headers sent from the server:

[image: server response headers]

So, the server sends the correct cookies. However, the browser only seems to store the first one (`age=44`). If I refresh the page again, these are the Request Headers being sent to the server:

[image: server request headers]

Only the first cookie (`age=44`) is sent. Logging `document.cookie` in the console also returns just `'age=44'`.

When inspecting the cookies from the Chrome's UI, I can also see that only the first one is saved:

What's the problem here?

[image: chrome ui cookies]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just using vanilla Node then you can simply pass an array as the second parameter to [`res.setHeader(field, value)`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
  'age=44; path=/',
  'name=ok; path=/',
  'something=else; path=/'
])
```

If using Express 4.11.0+ you can use [`res.append(field [, value])`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.append):

```
res.append('Set-Cookie', 'age=44; path=/');
res.append('Set-Cookie', 'name=ok; path=/');
res.append('Set-Cookie', 'something=else; path=/');
```

Comment: Thanks! I just looked at the node docs, it seems that if you try to set the same header multiple times with `res.setHeader`, only the last one will be used. Thanks for mentioning the array approach.